# Предлог "в": Положение о .... работе (В) ГУП КК "..."

Tags: грамматика

Правильно ли будет написать: «Положение о порядке ведения претензионно-исковой работы **в** ГУП КК "____"»?

Answer (score 0):

Если работы ведутся в ГУП КК , предлог В здесь оправдан. Тогда надо исправить заголовок -  Работы. Если же положение относится к работе ГУП КК , а не о работах в самом ГУП КК, тогда правильно: «Положение о порядке ведения претензионно-исковой работы ГУП КК».

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта возможны и в данном случае не несут какой-либо разницы. 
Я думаю, что здесь определяется более традицией данной организации, нежели какими-то смысловыми мотивами. Так что пишите, как начальство скажет. Мне вариант с предлогом кажется более понятным бюрократу, так что можете использовать.

По поводу самого предлога.
Здесь "В" не к работе относится, а к порядку. "Порядок в ГУП". Работа, понятно, в нем же и происходит, но о том нет смысла сообщать в заголовке. Так что это обычный канцелярский оборот, а не что-то хитро-заумное.